# Solve and find x for normally distributed functions

Tags: r, quadratic

I'm trying to solve a equation and find the value for `x` from it. I'm using the following code:

```
mu1 = 0
mu2 = 1
sigma1 = 0.5
sigma2 = 0.6
prior1 = 0.3
prior2 = 0.7

boundary = function(x) {
  return(( 1 / sqrt(2 * pi * sigma1)) * exp(-0.5 * ((x - mu1) / sigma1)^2)*prior1) - 
    ((1 / sqrt(2 * pi * sigma2)) * exp(-0.5 * ((x - mu2) / sigma2)^2)*prior2)
}
uniroot(boundary, c(-1e+05, 1e+07))
```

This does not give me correct answers. I'm pretty new to R and am not sure exactly how `uniroot` works.

- Is there a better way to solve this equation?
- Are there any packages available to solve this (similar to MATLAB's `solve()` function)?

Comment: So this function plots as a normal curve, but it will never actually reach 0 will it? It will just get smaller and smaller fading from x=0 to more extreme negative or positive values. I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to "solve".

Comment: yes,those are the equations of two normal curves. But there is only one unknown x in the equation. which means i should be able to solve it and find its value.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to solve. What is x doing? I suspect there will be an easier way to do whatever it is you are trying to do, once we know what that is. Also, note that your function is named `boundary`, whereas you are calling `decisionBoundary` w/i `unitroot`. Lastly, the `prior`s don't seem to be playing any role.

Comment: I'm trying to do bayesian analysis on normal distributions. The equation represents my discriminant function. solving for x will give me the decision boundary which separate's the two normal distributions. I have updated my question with the priors and corrected the uniroot function as well.

Comment: Re Q1:....analytically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten your code a little bit (and minimize the chance of typos) by using the built-in `dnorm()` function:

```
curve(dnorm(x,mean=0,sd=0.5),from=-4,to=4)
curve(dnorm(x,mean=0,sd=0.6),add=TRUE,col=2)
```

If I try `uniroot()` over a reasonable range, I get sensible answers:

```
uniroot(function(x) dnorm(x,0,0.5)-dnorm(x,0,0.6), c(0,5))  ## 0.546
uniroot(function(x) dnorm(x,0,0.5)-dnorm(x,0,0.6), c(-5,0)) ## -0.546
```

If I try to start from huge values, the calculation is going to underflow (whether you do it by hand or use `dnorm()`; the Gaussian goes below R's minimum representable valuable (see `?.Machine`) between 19 and 20.

```
dnorm(19,0,0.5)  ## 2e-314
dnorm(20,0,0.5)  ## 0
```

In some cases you can use `log=TRUE` in `dnorm()` to compute the log-probability and use that in computations instead, but here (as in many Bayesian computations) you're a bit stuck because you have to subtract the results.